# why v[0] and *v.begin() printing 0 even though i am not passing some 0 as input value for array

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int testcases = 0;
    int length;
    int item =0;

    std::vector<int> v;

    cin>>testcases;
    for (int i=0; i<testcases; ++i)
    {
        cin>>length;

        v.resize(length);
        for (int j=0; j<length; ++j)
        {

            cin >> item;
            cout << "item entered:" << item << endl;
            v.push_back(item);

        }

        cout << v[0] << " ";
        cout << *v.begin() << " ";

        int loop=0;
        cin>>loop;

        int range1=0, range2=0;


        int result = 0;
        for (int k=0; k<loop; ++k)
        {
            result = 0;
            cin>>range1;
            cin>>range2;
            cout << v[range1]<< " "<< v[range2] <<endl;
            while (range1<=range2)
            {
                result = result^v[range1];
                ++range1;
            }
            cout << result << endl;
        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

why v[0] and *v.begin() printing 0 even though i am not passing some 0 as input value for array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `push_back` calls add to the *end* of the vector, which is after the items created by the `resize` call.

If you want to set specific entries in the vector, you need to use array indexing syntax in the input loop.

Comment: Thanks . It solves the problem. i was stuck here from last 30 mins.